# How can i randomly select only one size in a two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, random

```java
String[] dizi_paragraf = dosya.split("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < dizi_paragraf.length; i++) {
    String[] dizi_cumle = dizi_paragraf[i].split("\\.");
    String[][] dizi_total = new String[dizi_paragraf.length][dizi_cumle.length];
    int[][] dizi = new int[dizi_paragraf.length][dizi_cumle.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < dizi_cumle.length; j++) {
        dizi_total[i][j] = dizi_cumle[j];
        dizi[i][j] = j;
        System.out.println(dizi[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0-0
0-1
1-0
1-1
1-2
2-0
3-0
3-1
4-0
4-1
5-0
5-1
5-2
5-3
```

I want this:

```
    0-1
    0-0
    1-1
    1-0
    1-2
    2-0
    3-1
    3-0
    4-0
    4-1
    5-3
    5-1
    5-0
    5-2
```

This is an example.
The value in j for each i changes randomly but until j length.
How can I do this? Have you any ideas?
For example, it should produce 0 or 1 for index 0. It should produce 0.1 or 2 for the 1st index. 2. You should take only 0 for indis. etc.
Just example. This can be change. I take this dynamically.

"i" must be constant. But j should be chosen randomly. for indice 0, j value: 0 and 1. This should be chosen randomly. for indice 1, j value: 0,1 and 2. This should be chosen randomly.

Comment: The code you provided does not match with the output.

Comment: I think output match with `i+"-"+j`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something as below:

```
        String dosya = "Test cumle 1. CUmle 2.\nCumle 3 here. Next sentences. Last sentences.";

        String[] dizi_paragraf = dosya.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < dizi_paragraf.length; i++) {
            String[] dizi_cumle = dizi_paragraf[i].split("\\.");
            String[][] dizi_total = new String[dizi_paragraf.length][dizi_cumle.length];
            int[][] dizi = new int[dizi_paragraf.length][dizi_cumle.length];

            List<Integer> jj = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < dizi_cumle.length; j++) {
                jj.add(j);
            }
            Collections.shuffle(jj);
            for (int j:jj) {
                dizi_total[i][j] = dizi_cumle[j];
                dizi[i][j] = j;
                System.out.println("dizi[i][j] "+i+"-"+j);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The following solution does not use Collection.shuffle, just Random generator and arrays.

```
String[] dizi_paragraf = dosya.split("\n");
Random r = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < dizi_paragraf.length; i++) {
    String[] dizi_cumle = dizi_paragraf[i].split("\\.");
    String[][] dizi_total = new String[dizi_paragraf.length][dizi_cumle.length];
    int[][] dizi = new int[dizi_paragraf.length][dizi_cumle.length];

    for (int j = 0; j < dizi_cumle.length; j++) {
        int rNumber = 0;
        boolean unique=false;
        while (!unique){
           unique=true;
           rNumber = r.nextInt(dizi_cumle.length);
            for (int jj = 0; jj < j; jj++) {
                if (dizi[i][jj] == rNumber) {
                    unique = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        dizi_total[i][j] = dizi_cumle[j];
        dizi[i][j] = rNumber;
        System.out.println(i + "-" + dizi[i][j]);
    }
}
```

For each j, the while loops starts with unique=false. It gets a random number `r.nextInt(dizi_cumle.length)` and sets the unique to true. Then it does a for loop on the dizi[][] array on the second dimension j, until it finds a previously set number. If the for loop ends without entering the `if (dizi[i][jj] == rNumber)` the unique is never set to false and the while exits. The number finally is set into the array.